# $\oint_{\gamma}\frac 1{z^2+1}dz$ on different curves

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$\oint_{\gamma}\frac 1{z^2+1}dz$ on the curves: $\gamma_1: |z + i| = 1$, $\gamma_2:|z - i| = 1$, $\gamma_3: |z| = \frac 12$, $\gamma_4: |z - i| = \frac 32$.
I would like to use the residue theorem and we see that we have $z_{1,2}=\pm i$.
Now it makes it a problem of in which of those circles which poles we have, right? For $\gamma_1$ we will only use $z = -i$ since it is the center of the circle and will always be there, do I have to consider both cases when $|z + i| < 1$ and $|z + i| > 1$? for each of them? Do you have any techniques to faster know if a pole is inside the curve or not? Or actually, how do I check that algebraically?

Comment: I think your $\;\gamma_2\;$ is missing an equality sign and has instead a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whi it is a problem: the only poles are the simple ones $\;\pm i\;$ ,so check:

$$\gamma_1: |-i+i|=0<1\;,\;\;|i+i|=2|>1\implies -i\;\text{ is in, $\,i\,$ is out}$$

...and etc. Do the same as above with all the other paths and check whether $\;-i\,,\,\,i\;$ are enclosed by the path...and then use that the given function is analytic anywhere in $\;\Bbb C\setminus\{-i,i\}\;$ .

Comment: An analytic function means that it is $olomorphe$, right? So to prove that a function is analitically I have to prove that it is differentiable? and so I only take the cases when the point is inside the curve? IF the curves wouldn't go in trigonometric sense, then I should've checker for say $|z + i| > 1$?

Comment: Also the $Res(f, -i) = \frac {-1}{2i}$? But then the integral would be $-\pi$ and I don't think that' correct

Comment: Oui, holomorphic is the same as analytic in this context. You won't have problems proving this if you already know that the ratio of two analytic functions is analytic wherever tyhe denominator function doesn't vanish, for example...About the residue: that is correct...and why do you thing the result, whatever it is, isn't correct?

Comment: It was a false thinking of mine, I thought that it shouldn't be negative, but then I thought that, Oh it's under the x axis so it can be negative

Comment: @C.Cristi You're working in the complex numbers: there is no positive and no negative here!

Comment: Yeah but the result of the integral is a real number

Comment: Ah, ok...didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You can rewrite 
$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=
\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}dz=\\
\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-i}dz-\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+i}dz$$
and use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz \tag{1}$$
where $f(z)=1$, depending on whether $z_1=-i$, $z_2=i$ fall inside or outside a particular disk bounded by the relevant $\gamma$.